# Haskell - Reading data from file and storing into a container

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in Haskell that gives me an error on the first line of bookFromFile function. What am I doing wrong?

The error code is down below.

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

type Book = (Int, String, String, String, String, String, String)

main = do
   inputFile <- openFile "catalogo.txt" ReadMode
   let b = (bookFromFile inputFile)
   print "done"

bookFromFile :: Handle -> Book
bookFromFile inputFile = do

   --Read&Store stuff from file
   isbn <- fmap read (hGetLine inputFile) :: IO Int
   title <- (hGetLine inputFile) 
   author <- (hGetLine inputFile)
   genre <- (hGetLine inputFile) 
   date <- (hGetLine inputFile) 
   publisher <- (hGetLine inputFile)
   summary <- (readSummary inputFile) --readSummary :: Handle -> IO String (works well)
   putStr (summary ++ "\n")

   --Construct and return a book
   (isbn, title, author, genre, date, publisher, summary)
```

Strangely, *(Int, String, String, String, String, String, Int)* is not even the type I have defined for book.
Error Message:

```
* Couldn't match type `IO'
                     with `(,,,,,,) Int String String String String String'
      Expected type: (Int, String, String, String, String, String, Int)
        Actual type: IO Int
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        isbn <- fmap read (hGetLine inputFile) :: IO Int
      In the expression:
        do { isbn <- fmap read (hGetLine inputFile) :: IO Int;
             putStr ((show isbn) ++ "\n");
             title <- (hGetLine inputFile);
             putStr (title ++ "\n");
             .... }
```

Comment: This code reads like C converted to Haskell, not idiomatic Haskell....  You should take advantage of Haskell laziness, `readFile`, `lines`, and a bunch of pure functions, which would really show off the reason to choose Haskell over C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are three small problems:

- `bookFromFile` needs to sit in `IO` - you can see this because you use functions like `hGetLine` and `putStr`
- when you then use it you have use `b <- bookFromFile...` instead of `let b = bookFromFile ...`
- and you have to `return` the tuple

also you can get rid of many of the `(...)` like this

```
main = do
   inputFile <- openFile "catalogo.txt" ReadMode
   b <- bookFromFile inputFile
   print "done"

bookFromFile :: Handle -> IO Book
bookFromFile inputFile = do
   --Read&Store stuff from file
   isbn <- fmap read (hGetLine inputFile)
   title <- hGetLine inputFile 
   author <- hGetLine inputFile
   genre <- hGetLine inputFile 
   date <- hGetLine inputFile 
   publisher <- hGetLine inputFile
   summary <- readSummary inputFile --readSummary :: Handle -> IO String (works well)
   putStr (summary ++ "\n")

   --Construct and return a book
   return (isbn, title, author, genre, date, publisher, summary)
```

Answer (score 2):

The type signature of `bookFromFile` has to be `Handle->IO Book`, since this function uses IO.

Also, since the function is in IO, you shouldn't call it using `let b = ....`, but use `b <- ....`.

You also need to use `return` on the last line of the function to actually wrap the value in the IO needed for the return.

Answer (score 1):

`bookFromFile` should properly make as much of the thinking pure as possible, so maybe something like this:

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

type Book = (Int, String, String, String, String, String, String)

bookFromStrings:: [String] -> Maybe Book
bookFromStrings [isbn,title,author,genre,date,publisher,summary] = 
       Just (read isbn,title,author,genre,date,publisher,summary)
bookFromStrings _ = Nothing

bookFromString :: String -> Maybe Book
bookFromString str = bookFromStrings (begin ++ [unlines rest]) where
      (begin, rest) = splitAt 6 (lines str)

bookFromHandle :: Handle -> IO (Maybe Book)
bookFromHandle h  = do
    str <- hGetContents h
    return (bookFromString str)

bookFromFile :: FilePath ->  IO (Maybe Book)
bookFromFile file = withFile file ReadMode bookFromHandle
```

It would be basically the same but nicer if you made a little record type for `Book`

```
 data Book = Book {isbn :: Int, title :: String ...}
```